# React / MUI Datagrid keeps reference to old rows causing memory leak

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, material-ui

In my React app I have the following component structure:

Component A (Home.js):

- has state that keeps an array of 10 Objects
- has a child Component B, which it passes that state to
- has a method that fetches 10 new Objects and sets the state to that data

Component B:

- receives the array of objects as props
- displays them in a MUI datagrid
- when changing the page in the datagrid, calls a callback from Component A that executes the fetch method

Now when I view the memory heap, I see those 10 objects. When I change the page of the datagrid in Component B, Component A fetches new data, creates 10 new objects from it, sets the state to a new array, and passes that down via props to B. That all works fine.

However, the 10 previous objects stay in memory for reasons I don't understand. If I repeat the process, the heap grows by 10 objects every time, even if the state is SET to the 10 new object (the 10 new objects are not ADDED, they replace the previous state).

Here my components (circumcised from code unlikely to influence the problem):

- Component A (Home):

  ```
        const Home = () => {
    const [results, setResults] = useState({});
    // store the url for the next/previous page from server pagination. I stripped the part where this is set, since its irrelevant here.
    const [nextPageLink, setNextPageLink] = useImmer({ Patient: "" });
    const [prevPageLink, setPrevPageLink] = useImmer({ Patient: "" });


    // function that fetches 10 new rows, either next 10 or previous 10
    const updatePage = async (nextOrPrev) => {
        if (nextOrPrev == "next") {
            if (!nextPageLink["Patient"]) return;
            else {
                const result = await getPageData(nextPageLink["Patient"]);
                console.log(result);
                setNextPageLink((prev) => {
                    return { ...prev, Patient: result["nextLink"] };
                });
                setPrevPageLink((prev) => {
                    return { ...prev, Patient: result["prevLink"] };
                });
                setResults((prev) => {
                    return { ...prev, Patient: result["data"] };
                });
            }
        } else if (nextOrPrev == "previous") {
            if (!prevPageLink["Patient"]) return;
            else {
                const result = await getPageData(prevPageLink["Patient"]);
                console.log(result);
                setNextPageLink((prev) => {
                    return { ...prev, Patient: result["nextLink"] };
                });
                setPrevPageLink((prev) => {
                    return { ...prev, Patient: result["prevLink"] };
                });
                setResults((prev) => {
                    return { ...prev, Patient: result["data"] };
                });
            }
        } 
    };

    // render section
    return (
        <CustomDataGrid
            key={resourceType}
            resourceType={resourceType}
            columns={columns}
            rows={results[resourceType]}
            rowCount={resultCount[resourceType]}
            updatePage={updatePage}
        />
    );
  ```

  };
- Component B (Custom component containing the datagrid):

```
export default function CustomDataGrid({
    resourceType,
    columns,
    rows,
    rowCount,
    updatePage,
}) {
    const [paginationModel, setPaginationModel] = React.useState({
        page: 0,
        pageSize: 10,
    });
    const [loading, setloading] = useState(false);
    const nextOrPrev = useRef("");

      // When I change the page, call the callback from Component A (Home) to fetch 10 new rows
    useEffect(() => {
        updatePage(resourceType, nextOrPrev.current);
    }, [paginationModel.page]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setloading(false);
    }, [rows]);



    return (
            <DataGrid
                rows={rows}
                columns={columns}
                rowsPerPageOptions={[10]}
                pageSize={10}
                        // Change the page of the datagrid
                onPageChange={(newPage) => {
                    nextOrPrev.current =
                        newPage > paginationModel.page ? "next" : "previous";
                    setPaginationModel({ ...paginationModel, page: newPage });
                }}
                
                onSelectionModelChange={(newSelection) => {
                    if (!loading) setSelectedResources(newSelection);
                }}
                selectionModel={selectedResources}
                experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}
                disableVirtualization
                rowCount={rowCount}
                paginationModel={paginationModel}
                paginationMode="server"
                pagination
                keepNonExistentRowsSelected
            />
    );
}
```

As I said, the display and fetching and stuff all works fine, the only problem is that the memory is growing and growing with every page change, even though I don't specifically keep references to  previous rows anywhere in my code, but they're still not garbage collected. Would appreciate any help I can get!

EDIT: I tried both useState and useImmer, makes no difference.

Comment: JavaScripts garbage collection isn't necessarily instant and it won't clean up anything that is still being referenced. Don't really have enough information on this one. It could be that your `getPageData` uses some sort of cache that is holding onto the data. It could be a bug with `experimentalFeatures` that you are using. It could be a bug in the core grid. This seems better suited as an issue on the github repo: https://github.com/mui/mui-x